# Error with std::vector push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I am trying to use the std::vector push_back method to insert Node objects into a vector that stores template Node objects.  The error I am getting I believe is saying that the input I am using for the push_back method is not the correct type? Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: `vector<Node<T> > v;` is sufficient to create a vector. No new needed here. Note this creates a local variable. Same with your map. If they are class members, you don't need to put them again in the constructor like that. It serves no purpose.

Comment: The best thing to do is post a short complete example so we don't need to guess what your class definitions look like, etc.  Your constructor looks quite wrong.   If you mean to initialize member variables use the initializer list, don't create new variables that immediately go out of scope.

Comment: Alright, so I removed the pointless vector and map that were created in the constructor, but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: @user2932450: So what type is `v`? Specifically, is it something that stores nodes or (as the error message implies) something that stores `int` values?

Comment: @MikeSeymour v is a vector that stores Nodes<T>. So in the case above I created a PriorityQueue<int> pqueue, which will stores Nodes<int> in a vector<Nodes<int> >

Comment: @user2932450: Really? The error message says it's a `vector<int>`.  Perhaps you should check its declaration again.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It is a vector<int> because of the test case that I use. I just made an edit to add the test case. Where I declare a PriorityQueue<int>, which will have a vector v that stores Nodes<int>.

Comment: @user2932450 post a MCVE. That doesn't mean dump all your code; but post something that someone else can compile to get the same error message.

Comment: @user2932450: That makes no sense. If you want it to store nodes, then it will have to be `vector<Node<T>>`. `vector<int>` can only store `int` values, and so will give this error if you try to store another type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the error message, it looks like `v` (the class member, not the weird and pointless local variable in the constructor) is declared `vector<int>*` (or perhaps `vector<T>*`) when it should be `vector<Node<T>>`.

Comment: Right, it's declared as a vector<int> because of the test case that I use. I'll add an edit that shows the test case.

Comment: @user2932450: So why are your trying to put a `Node<T>` in it, when it stores `int`?

Comment: Node<T> and PriorityQueue<T> are both template classes. PriorityQueue<T> can store Nodes<T> of any type. So therefore the vector<Nodes<T> >, v, can store Nodes<T> of any type.

Comment: @user2932450: Are you absolutely sure that `v` is `vector<Node<T>>`? The error message quite clearly says that it isn't: it's a `vector<int>`. Please check (and show us) the declaration of `v`.